Is there LTS for C++, if not, how?
my goal is to keep up to date with C++. I am going to study about Incremental Learning. I want to use C++ and Python for this. So, versioning is part of things that I want to know.
My point of view:

I was taught with Java. Java have LTS i.e. Java 8. So, my teacher taught me with Java 8.
Migrated to Go. Go have Release Policy, i.e. every 2 major release. So, I always use the latest version.
Learnt Python. Python have a end-of-life policy. So, I use Python 3.12
Use React and Angular for Web. Node have LTS. So, I use the current LTS.
Note: After some thought, I never know about the JavaScript version that I am using. It is handled by the framework.

I am googling for C++ and can't find C++ LTS. May I know whether C++11 is still receiving security patches?

There's no single C++ compiler. There are three major ones: Clang, GCC, MSVC. Each of them has stable releases, and older releases presumably get some minimal updates.

C++ has a rolling 3 year release plan since C++11 ie (C++14, C++17, C++20 and, C++23, etc) see Standard C++ Current Status.  Security patches are up to the individual C++ vendors.

There is no real "LTS". The compiler vendors and their C(++) Runtime has an ABI.
That ABI is mostly stable and rarely breaks (which is why C++98 code mostly compiles fine in new versions of the runtime.)
If there is the need for a patch, the ABI does not break, but the implementation of the runtime changes. C++ is incremental in that regard. It gets new stuff and very very rarely deprecates other stuff. std::vector for example is considered a mistake. but exists since C++98 because no one wants to break the ABI.

all those mentioned languages have a "runtime" that gets updates, while C++ compiles directly to assembly .... so the idea of a "security patch" doesn't apply to the language, it instead applies to the software written in that language, so don't expect to see a "C++ security update", the language is however getting improved but this improvement has no effect on the code that's already compiled to assembly, there could be updates to the "platform standard library" such as windows "visual c++ redistributable packages" though.

Ultimately, if you're a library developer, you usually want to support the three big compilers, and support the few latest stable versions of each. If you're a desktop application developer, you can usually just use the latest version of your single most favorite compiler (unless that compiler is MSVC, then you need another one for non-Windows targets). More exotic platforms may or may not limit you to certain versions of certain compilers.

There is a C++ standard which is updated every few years. And there isn't really an end-of-life thing in C++. Every now and then some things get deprectated and then later removed from the language (but you usually have years to adapt). And NO C++11 will not get patches, sometimes the runtime libraries (dynamic link libraries) do and maybe that's what you're looking for?

@AhmedAEK Not completely true sometimes the C++ runtime libraries (compiled versions) get updated because of security patches (or even small bugfixes). But sure they're nothing like full java or python runtime updates.

May I know whether C++11 is still receiving security patches? -- Your own coding and application is responsible for being secure, not the C++ language itself.  For example, if your application has a buffer overrun (which can be used to exploit your application), it is your responsibility to fix the application, as the C++ language has no such facility to check for your mistakes "out-of-the-box".

Java is a product from Oracle. In that context LTS makes sense.  C++ is a language implemented by many vendors.  Individual compilers may have LTS, but it does not really apply to C++ itself.
The standard is the standard, and most compilers have a means to enforce earlier standards at least to C++98 (the first ISO standard).
Java is not defined by a standards body, so LTS  is more important.  Also Java has a runtime VM, where C++ compiles to native code, so no runtime not included in the executable or provided by the OS.

Just slightly oversimplified. There are many Java vendors too.

@Anonymous There are other Java VMs true, but the question refers to Java 8 which is an Oracle product.
